# MEF: DirectoryPartCatalog

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I'm trying to write a simple [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FileExplorer) demo to learn about it. I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/simple-introduction-to-extensible-applications-with-the-managed-extensions-framework) tutorial, but it seems to be outdated. The downloadable example works, but it uses an included assembly that is 2 versions older (2008.9.4.0) than the current one (4.0) that ships with Framwework 4.

In particular, it uses DirectoryPartCatalog that I cannot find anywhere in the newest library. Could anyone provide an example on how to discover pluggable assemblies from a directory with the current version of MEF?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make several changes to make this sample compile and run with builtin version of System.ComponentModel.Composition.

```
class Program
{
    [ImportMany] // [Import]
    public IEnumerable<string> Messages { get; set; }

    [ImportMany] // [Import]
    public IEnumerable<IOutputString> OutputSet { get; set; }

    [Import("OutputMessages")]
    public Action<IEnumerable<IOutputString>, IEnumerable<string>> OutputMessages { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(); // AggregatingComposablePartCatalog
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\..\ExternalMessages\bin\Debug")); // DirectoryPartCatalog
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\..\ExtraMessages")); // DirectoryPartCatalog
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())); // AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog); // CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateResolver());

        // container.AddPart(this);
        // container.Compose();
        container.ComposeParts(this);

        OutputMessages(OutputSet, Messages);

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this it fixed a lot of my problems.

Answer (score 2):

DirectoryPartCatalog is now called [DirectoryCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think, that you are searching for [DirectoryCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.aspx)